# NULL values sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables :

```
athlete , epreuve , rangindividuel
```

I want all athletes that have never been discalified from test ( disqualified means that rang
IS NULL). An athlete can participate in one or multiple tests.
I tried this :

```
SELECT a.aid,
       COUNT(e.epid) 
FROM rangindividuel ri,
     athlete a,
     epreuve e
WHERE a.aid = ri.aid
  AND e.epid = ri.epid 
GROUP BY aid
HAVING SUM(ri.rang) IS NOT NULL;
```

I don t know why it doesn't work

Comment: Can you add some sample data, and the expected output?

Comment: `SUM()` can never be `NULL` in a query like this, so this will return all the rows in the joined tables.

Comment: `SUM(ri.rang)` only sums the non-NULL values.

Comment: how can I fix this ?

Comment: Actually, I was a little wrong. If `rang` can be `NULL`, the sum will be null only if *all* the values of `rang` for an `aid` are null.

Comment: it isn't clear exactly what you want, but `SUM(ri.rang is null)=0` may be it?

Comment: @ysth That will also work, you should post it as a solution.

Comment: yes thank you . but i didn't really understand SUM(ri.rang is null)=0 . can you explain it please ?

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax everywhere. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Answer (score 1):

`SUM(rang)` will only be `NULL` if *all* the values of `rang` for an athlete are `NULL`. But if there are a mixture of NULL and non-NULL values, you'll get the sum of the non-NULL values.

Use a self-join with a query that returns all the athletes that have been disqualified, and filter them out.

```
SELECT r1.aid, COUNT(*)
FROM rangindividuel AS r1
LEFT JOIN rangindividuel AS r2 ON r1.aid = r2.aid AND r2.rang IS NULL
WHERE r2.aid IS NULL
GROUP BY r1.aid
```

Comment: It was left from an earlier version of the answer, before I saw that it should contain `COUNT(*)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
HAVING SUM(ri.rang IS NULL)=0
```

`ri.rang is null` returns true if they are disqualified or false if not disqualified. In numeric context, true and false are just 1 and 0.  When you sum them for all an athlete's tests, you will get 0 as the sum only if all the summed expressions were false, that is only if they were never disqualified.

As mentioned in a comment, you are using the old, deprecated, awkward and hard to read comma-join syntax.  You should use explicit joins with on clauses.  So instead of:

```
FROM rangindividuel ri,
     athlete a,
     epreuve e
WHERE a.aid = ri.aid
  AND e.epid = ri.epid
```

do:

```
FROM rangindividuel ri
JOIN athlete a ON a.aid = ri.aid
JOIN epreuve e ON e.epid = ri.epid
```